# How can i create sections and add items to do sections with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was wondering how can i create a section, and by section i mean something like this

[image]

And in those sections, each button add something like Item 1, Item 2.

Comment: this is a bit generic, what code you have so far?

Comment: Indeed it is. So far what i have is an object that has an id and another property that returns a JSX with an h1 and a button. That is the section. And i have a state hook that has a empty array as it's useState. So everytime i click one button, i pass that object into the array and then i render it with the array map. What i don't know is how can i add items to show below those sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by fixing your state, right now you are only keeping track of `id` and `title` but if you want to have different items for each section you have to save those in your state as well. Your sections state should then look something like this:

```
const [sections, setSections] = useState([
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Test section 1',
    items: ['item 1', 'item 2'],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Test section 2',
    items: ['item a', 'item b'],
  },
]);
```

Then you can have a `Section` component that renders a single section, its items and a button to add a new item. This button will call a callback that you define in your parent and pass down:

```
// This is defined in the parent, where your state lives
const addItem = (index, item) => {
  const newSections = sections.slice();
  newSections[index].items.push(item);
  setSections(newSections);
};
```

You will then map your sections into `Section` components and pass down the callback.

```
{sections.map((section, index) => (
  <Section
    section={section}
    key={section.id}
    addItem={(item) => addItem(index, item)}
  />
))}
```

In your `Section` component you can then call that callback passing the value of the item you want to add.

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mni8p7?file=src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, but i have a few questions, if you don't mind. At the `const addItem`, where are you defining item and index?

Comment: `item` is passed when it's called in the `Section` component (If you look at the demo it should be clearer). `index` is taken straight from `map` function, you can have it a second optional parameter.

Comment: Ok, got it! About the addSection function, you pass title as a parameter, and then you call that function with newSectionTitle as a parameter. I don't really get it.

Comment: so `addSection` takes in a title and adds to the list of sections in your state a  new section with that title. `newSectionTitle` it's just another piece of state that i used to save the value of the input field